# Android Circle button

Tags: android, button

How I can to make custom  **circle button**? (only make clicks on circle )

Is any way to make it with circle png file?

I tried with imageView override onTouch method but it works very badly because view.getWidth(), view.getHeight() and view.getTop... methods works very bad

```
public boolean inCircle(MotionEvent e, int radius, int x, int y) {
    int dx = (int) (e.getX() - x);
    int dy = (int) (e.getY() - y);
    double d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
    if (d < radius)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914329/round-button-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049868/round-button-in-android-avoid-presses-outside-the-button

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/arlindiDev/CircleCheckBox

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple. Create a custom shape drawable and set that as the background of your view. Example:

round_button_drawable.xml in drawable/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
</shape>
```

set this drawable as the background of any view.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_drawable"
    android:text="btn"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to extend `Button` and override its `onDraw` method 
You can then draw a circle on the `canvas` using `canvas.drawCircle` method.

You can also draw the `circle.png` file on the canvas using `Drawable.draw` method

Comment: IMHO too complicated suggestion.. :S he need to implement redrawing for change of button states as well? why to invent already invented wheel?

Comment: I was just giving him another option.

Comment: approved ;) don't get me wrong, I just think there is much simpler solution ;) cheers

Comment: Yes I agree this may be kind of overkill

Comment: I have buttons under my circle button and I need to make them also clickable

Comment: what do you mean by buttons under my button ? Do you mean a button inside a button ?

Answer (score 0):

there is [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) class which can serve ur purpose..

Comment: Somebody who went mad and voted negative on all answers should comment what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Dont go for complex logic just select any rounded image and set that image as a background of your simple button it will look like simple round button and it will accept click only on that round shape.

Comment: I have buttons under my circle button and I need to make them also clickable

Comment: button under circle button means what...?