# Android: How to avoid presses outside the circle of a round button using wrap content?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, imagebutton

Can anyone tell me how to avoid presses outside the circle of a round button since "wrap_content" doesn't seem to work. I used an image file to create the button. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: maybe the linked answers may help you: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266595/how-to-make-a-round-button (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049868/round-button-in-android-avoid-presses-outside-the-button

Comment: With a default `Button` you can't as the view will be a rectangle/square. If you create your own `Button` class then you could determine if the user touched the `Button` outside the circle and ignore that event. There are some questions regarding the exact situation, search stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Only for Your understanding.. (By default android View is in Rectangle shape so it apply same for Button)

1. Set **Touch Listener** to your button and in `onTouch()` map X-Y co-ordinates for Circle area.
   If it lies in inside area do what you want else return **false**.
2. Use `Inset` look at this tutorial http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/07/01/button-hit-area-for-custom-graphics/
3. Implement **TouchDelegates** look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/04/15/android-using-touchdelegates/