# ImageView is covering overlaying button's ripple effect

Tags: android, material-design

I have an ImageView acting as a background to a Relativelayout with a refresh button sitting on top of it. The button's ripple effect is being covered by the ImageView underneath it. I've tried FrameLayouts etc but nothing seems to help.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/sidebar_bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/device_bg" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sidebar_refresh" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code for ripple xml and code where you are triggering the ripple effect

Comment: @prem I'm not using ripple.xml I'm using Android's built in ripple effect by using android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" It works fine until I add the ImageView below it.

Answer (score 1):

With `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, you can do like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/device_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sidebar_refresh" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sidebar_refresh"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The key is the ripple effect must has it's own layouts(**LinearLayout+FrameLayout**), then use `alpha="0"`to set transparent to image which has ripple in order to overlay image which is solid.

The problem with this code is:

1. You have to hard code the padding. If no padding or padding too small, the ripple effect will bound to rectangular, not circle. Use formula 48(height/width)/7 to figure out the padding. If divide by 7 doesn't work, decrease the divisor, e.g. 6.
2. Because it has padding, so you can't touch padding to trigger ripple effect. It's acceptable if this is a small button because of not obvious, but it does matter if it's a big button.

The good news is there's an alternative way to simulate `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` with `ripple` tag in `drawable/ripple.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorPrimary">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</ripple>
```

From what i observed, it give the same ripple effect(except it doesn't have overflow ripple) like `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` do, so no reason you insist to use default `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`

With this `ripple.xml`, do like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/device_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sidebar_refresh" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ripple" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only changed was `LinearLayout` part. No more hard-coded padding and no alpha image. The only minor problem was clicking corner will still trigger ripple effect. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049868/round-button-in-android-avoid-presses-outside-the-button) but i haven't tried.

The two ways above work even the image is not transparent.